# Trying to insert multiple variable in print to check if the variable is getting inserted correctly

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to insert two variables which are got from users & text file in json payload. But i am getting Key error

Code

```
print ('{"ip-address": "x.x.x.x","user-name": "john","password": "{}","db-name": "{}","service-name": "Sql","port": #"000","connection-string": "xxx"}'.format(Pass,x.strip()))
```

Error

```
KeyError: '"ip-address"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `.format()` or f-strings you need to be more careful with your curly braces. Leaving a single `{` or `}` gets misinterpreted. If you want to print a single `{` when using `.format()` or f-strings you need to instead add `{{`.

e.g.

```py
name = 'foo'
print(f'{name} }')
```

gives a syntax error. But:

```py
name = 'foo'
print(f'{name} }}')
```

gives the desired output: `>>> foo }`.